# pushViewController on UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a TabBarController with 3 Views / Tabs...At one Tab i have an UITableView. Now i want if the user clicks on a cell switch to a detailview...i tried it already with this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
DetailViewController *nextController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailView"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];

}
```

But it doen´s work...Any Ideas?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed the table view controller in a navigation controller

Comment: @user1370245 Instead of making the tab's view a tableviewcontroller, make it a navigation controller, then set the navigation controller's root view to your table view controller.  Are you using Storyboards or separate xibs?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use navigation controller do like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//for home tab.. u want to add navigation controller 
YourTableViewController *objviewController = [[[YourTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourTableViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initRootViewController:objviewController]; 

//for tab2...
YourSecondViewController *objYourSecondViewController =  [[[YourTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourSecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];

//for  tab3...
YourThirdViewController *objYourThirdViewController =  [[[YourThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourThirdViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navCtrl,objYourSecondViewController,objYourThirdViewController,nil];

self.window.rootViewController=self.tabBarController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

---

But u can add also add like if don't need navigation controller:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  DetailViewController *nextController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailView"];

  [self.view addSubView:nextController];
}
```